# Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded Javascript

Tags: javascript

Al presionar en el boton el programa entero colapsa mandando ese error, da igual que haya datos en los input o no...

```js
let nombre = document.getElementById("nombre").value;
let edad = document.getElementById("edad").value;
let nota = document.getElementById("notaMedia").value;
let boton = document.getElementById("boton");

boton.onclick = function (e) {
    if (nombre == null || edad == null || nota == null) {
        alert("Datos incorrectos");
    } else {
        let estudiante = new Estudiante(nombre, edad, nota);
        alert(estudiante.getData());
    }
}

class Estudiante {
    constructor(nombre, edad, notaMedia) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.edad = edad;
        this.notaMedia = notaMedia;
    }

    get nombre() {
        return this.nombre;
    }

    set nombre(name) {
        this.nombre = name;
    }

    get edad() {
        return this.edad;
    }

    set edad(age) {
        this.edad = age;
    }

    get notaMedia() {
        return this.notaMedia;
    }

    set notaMedia(media) {
        this.notaMedia = media;
    }

    getData() {
        return "Nombre: " + this.nombre + ",\nEdad: " + this.edad + ",\nNota Media: " + this.notaMedia;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Ejercicio 3 usando POO</title>
</head>

<body>
    Nombre: <input type="text" name="" id="nombre"><br>
    Edad: <input type="text" name="" id="edad"><br>
    Nota Media: <input type="text" name="" id="notaMedia"><br>
    <input type="button" value="Almacenar" id="boton">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Debes capturar los valores de los inputs **dentro** del manejador de eventos del clic del botón. Empieza por eso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inicialmente, debes declarar las variables dentro de la función, para que ya las tome con valores, si las declaras cuando carga la página, serán valores en blanco siempre, no nulos.
El código es mucho mas sencillo que lo que intentas, te tejo un ejemplo funcional.

```
    let boton = document.getElementById("boton");
    class Estudiante {
        constructor(nombre, edad, notaMedia) {
            this.nombre = nombre;
            this.edad = edad;
            this.notaMedia = notaMedia;
        }
        getData() {
            return "Nombre: " + this.nombre + ",\nEdad: " + this.edad + ",\nNota Media: " + this.notaMedia;
        }
    }
    boton.onclick = function (e) {
        let nombre = document.getElementById("nombre").value;
        let edad = document.getElementById("edad").value;
        let nota = document.getElementById("notaMedia").value
        if (nombre == "" || edad == "" || nota == "") {
            alert("Datos incorrectos");
        } else {
            let estudiante = new Estudiante(nombre, edad, nota);
            alert(estudiante.getData());
        }
    }
```

**EDIT:**

Aqui va el nuevo código con las aclaraciones que hizo el autor de la pregunta.

```
let boton = document.getElementById("boton");

boton.onclick = function (e) {
    let nombre = document.getElementById("nombre").value;
    let edad = document.getElementById("edad").value;
    let nota = document.getElementById("notaMedia").value;
    if (nombre == null || edad == null || nota == null) {
        alert("Datos incorrectos");
    } else {
        let estudiante = new Estudiante(nombre, edad, nota);
        alert(estudiante.getData());
    }
}

class Estudiante {
    constructor(nombre, edad, notaMedia) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.edad = edad;
        this.notaMedia = notaMedia;
    }

    get nombre1() {
        return this.nombre;
    }

    set nombre1(name) {
        this.nombre = name;
    }

    get edad1() {
        return this.edad;
    }

    set edad1(age) {
        this.edad = age;
    }

    get notaMedia1() {
        return this.notaMedia;
    }

    set notaMedia1(media) {
        this.notaMedia = media;
    }

    getData() {
        return "Nombre: " + this.nombre1 + ",\nEdad: " + this.edad1 + ",\nNota Media: " + this.notaMedia1;
    }
}
```

Al utilizar los `Get` y `set` estabas asignándole un nombre igual al de las variables definidas en la clase, eso te estaba generando el error. Simplemente cambié el nombre agregando un 1 al final (no es una buena práctica utilizar los mismos nombres de variables agregando números, pero ejemplifica lo que necesitas para la solución).
Espero te sirva. Exitos

Comment: Pero tu lo que haces es borrar todos los getter y setter, aunque funcione el programa (si funciona, lo comprobé), quiero tener la posibilidad de modificar los atributos del objeto a través de los setter, pero me sigue dando el mismo error si los dejo

Comment: @GreenLass Por eso debes ser mas claro a la hora de preguntar. No veía la necesidad de los get y set en tu código. Por eso los eliminé en la respuesta.

Comment: @GreenLass fijate ahora si el código que te pasé en la respuesta resuelve tus dudas. Es un problema de los nombres de variables que utilizas.

Comment: Si, ahora si que funciona. Entonces no puedo llamar los getter y setter como las variables?